What is the reason for the discrepancy between the total number of non-N bases and the total length of the human genome assembly on the NCBI website?
I've been digging into the human genome assembly data and I've stumbled upon a discrepancy that I couldn't resolve on my own. I'd appreciate any insights or explanations from the biology community.
According to the NCBI website:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/grc/human/data?asm=GRCh38.p14
the total non-N base count (bases other than A, T, G or C) for the GRCh38.p14 assembly is 3,137,300,923. However, when I add up the total lengths of all the chromosomes, I get a total of 3,099,734,149. This leaves a discrepancy of 37,566,774 bases.
I've checked the data for alternate loci, FIX patches, and NOVEL patches, but they don't seem to account for the entire discrepancy. I've also looked into the RefSeq and GenBank databases, but I couldn't find any information that would explain the difference.
Can anyone help me understand where the extra 37 million bases are coming from? Is this a known issue, or am I missing something obvious?
Thanks in advance for your help!

I'd suggest directly contacting NCBI to resolve this. They have a somewhat funky ontology. It might help to understand how you did your math for adding up CHR lengths/alts/etc.

You might also ask our sister site Bioinformatics SE by requesting migration to that site.

I had to do a search to find out what non-N bases are — it isn't at all obvious from the name — so I modified your question to include an explanation.
